# nginx try_files downloads php-file instead of loading it

Tags: php, nginx

I'm trying to set up my nginx-server to accomplish the following

```
x.com opens index.php in /

x.com/example opens example.php in /

x.com/example/ opens example.php in /

x.com/foo/example opens example.php in /foo/
```

I have the following configuration

```
server {
listen www.delibr.com:443 default_server;  # if this is not a default server, remove "default_server"
root /var/delibr.se;
index index.php index.html index.htm; # this is also irrelevant

server_name www.delibr.com;
ssl_certificate /path to/crt;
ssl_certificate_key /path to/key;

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH:!aNULL;

location /beta {
    return 302 /#signup-form;
}

location / {
   try_files $uri $uri.php $uri/;
    if ($host != 'www.delibr.com') {
        rewrite     ^ https://www.delibr.com$request_uri? permanent;
    }
}

location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

    # With php5-fpm:
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

With this setup /example downloads example.php and /example/ gives 500 Internal Server error. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `try_files` should be as below

```
try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.php;
```

All parameter except the last one is tested in current context. So you when you use `$uri.php` and the file is found, the current context is meant to serve it as a static file, which it does. But for the last parameter it will check against other locations blocks in the config.

**Edit-1**

Your request for `x.com/example/ opens example.php in /` is not a usual one and it was a bit tricky to make it work. When we have the `$uri.php` in `try_files` it changes the url to `x.com/example/.php`. So we need to handle this url additionally by adding one additional block

```
location ~* /\.php {
   rewrite ^(.*)/\.php$ $1.php redirect;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Almost worked. But it didn't solve `x.com/example/ opens example.php in /` it generates "No input file specified."

Comment: Yes that is obvious let me check something quick

Comment: I tried to add `rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;`and that solves it but generates a new problem. Then subfolders that actually have a index.html doesn't work.